# How to add Resharper custom syntax rules for HTML

Tags: syntax, resharper

I want to add a custom rule to Resharper for HTML so it will highlights the mistakes:

The rule I want to add is, element id should be camel case starting with upper case:

```
<div id ="ThisIsCorrect"></div> => correct
```

but not:

```
<div id ="thisIs-Wrong"></div> => wrong!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done out of the box. You can create a Structural Search and Replace pattern to look for HTML tags with attributes were the value matches a regex pattern, but it looks like the pattern is case-insensitive, so it won't be able to match what you're after.

I've added a feature request for you to track and vote, for a future version to make the placeholder case sensitive: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-429097

Comment: thanks for the reply and creating a request, I hope they will consider it as part of the future development.